# Full screen mode under kde with any window

Tags: kde, window-manager, fullscreen, kde4

I found my new favorite shortcut (under kubuntu 14.04) `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`f` which brings applications like okular or kate to full screen. Unfortunately it does not work with konsole, chrome, etc. which brings me to the question: Why, and how to do it anyway?

Comment: Presumably those applications have their own shortcuts: F11, usually.

Comment: Wow, most annoying shortcut ever if you don't know it and you do it accidentally. There's literally no clear way other than using the shortcut again, to undo the full screen mode on a window once you're in that mode. I was going crazy trying to figure out what was wrong with my computer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**KWIN Global Keyboard Shortcut**

KDE System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Global Keyboard Shortcuts

Add a 'Make Window Fullscreen' shortcut to the KWIN

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is a window manager setting, not a setting for the KDE applications. Some applications really don't like if the window manager forces the window into fullscreen.